# Bootstrap Date Picker not working in angularJS application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, metronic

I am trying to Use a datepicker in my Angular application, I could not integrate Angular Datepicker ,So trying the basic theme provided datepicker.

It was working Fine till i integrate with angular.

This is my Input for date picker HTML,

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 mobile-width">
    <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker" size="16" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="help-block"> Select date </span>
</div>
```

Let me briefly Provide all the CSS and JS , i have included in my index.html

CSS:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<link href="bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/css/angular-datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--  <link href="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/src/css/angular-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
-->
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->

 <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
 <link href="assets/css/components-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
 <link href="assets/css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
 <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
 <link href="assets/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="assets/css/blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
```

Date picker uses bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css

JS-

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/angular-datatables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!--  <script src="assets/js/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->


  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-httpi/lib/httpi.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/http/http.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script> -->


  <script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/config/routes.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/config/environment/connections.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/config/environment/environment.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/config/api/api.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/login/services/login.service.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/login/controllers/login.controller.js"></script>


  <script src="app/scripts/company/services/company_service.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/company/controllers/company_controller.js"></script>

  <script src="app/scripts/user/services/user_service.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/user/controllers/user_controller.js"></script>

  <script src="app/scripts/group/services/group_service.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/group/controllers/group_controller.js"></script>



  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
  <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->

  <!-- <script src="assets/js/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
  <!--  <script src="assets/js/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="./js/table-datatables-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script src="assets/js/navbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
  <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="assets/js/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="assets/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/components-date-time-pickers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="assets/js/dashboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="assets/js/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
```

What i feel I might be wrong is,
There is Bower Component Jquery which is of version 3.0.0 , which is required for Many of my other angular integrations.

and i have my own copy of jquery which is of version - 1.11.3 , is it conflicting i dont know.

I have included both in my index file.
If i try to remove the Bower componenet's Jquery, whole application crashes.

Even if i have both the Datepicker is not working.

Metronic theme - http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/components_date_time_pickers.html

The first Defaul Datepicker i am trying to integrate.

Or i wont mind even if i can integrate any other Datepicker too,

I dont know where i am going wrong. help me out

Comment: what the error you are getting on console?

Comment: Hello Sayeed, I am not getting any Error in the console. Thats the major problem,